# Effect of combining baking powder and vinegar powders in a rub or seasoning blend

Tags: vinegar

I am currently working on a line of seasoning blends and rubs and I was curious, I know that both vinegar powder and baking powder are commonly used to dry rub meat and gain a more tender end result and I am sure we all remember the elementary school volcanos using vinegar and baking soda.

I was wondering if there would be a similar effect, at least to a degree, on the proteins of a rubbed roast or loin on the molecular level. I am not expecting to see it fizz and bubble but what would be the result of the two combining with the moisture in the meat itself.

Comment: Considering that one is an acid and one a base - which both can break down the proteins and thus be a tenderizer - and that they *neutralize* each other (-> the volcano)… not so sure about the idea. But I am not a chemist.

Comment: @Stephie it would depend on the ratios of the two chemicals and exactly which acid it was (probably acetic acid from vinegar) as to whether they would react completely with each-other and thereby both be neutralized.

Comment: Are you sure it's baking powder (a mix of sodium bicarbonate (base) and potassium bitrartrate (acid)) not simply baking soda (sodium bicarbonate)? If the former it is an odd combination to use, as dampening will result in the two reacting and fizzing, which is why baking powder is used in cooking - to rise/leaven doughs. Bicarb alone won't react, but will tenderize.

Answer (score 1):

Both acid or base conditions will denature proteins, leading to tenderization for the depth the marinade is able to penetrate. Most seasoning compounds will only be able to penetrate a very shallow layer from the surface, on the scale of millimetres.
Sodium is the exception, as it can penetrate deeply.

Depending on the ratio used, vinegar powder and baking powder will cancel each other's effect on pH  once hydrated. Vinegar powder can still contribute a vinegar taste as the acetic acid will still be present, though at an equilibrium in the acidic and non-acidic state. The same applies for baking powder.

Other than tenderization, baking powder's effect in increasing pH facilitates Maillard browning reactions. Baking powder is used instead of baking soda in more modern cooking applications since the bitartrate/tartaric acid component partially neutralizes it, leading to a less drastic effect on pH and more balanced flavour profile - baking soda alone may contribute to metallic or soapy tastes if added in excess of what the acids present in the foods can neutralise.